# Spark Dataframe concat and/or sum across all rows of a column based on column type

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

I am trying to find the concat of a column if it is string and sum if the column is int in a spark dataframe

Consider following table

```
+-------+-----------+
|   name|  price    | 
+-------+-----------+
|    abc|   20      | 
|    pqr|    2      |
|    uvw|   20      |
+-------+-----------+
```

I am expecting following output

```
+-------------------+-----------+
|   name            |  price    | 
+-------------------+-----------+
|    abc-pqr-uvw    |   42      | 
+-------------------+-----------+
```

I have tried aggregate and other functions, but since there is no key column to aggregate, i couldn't apply native spark functions. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **aggregate** function **`concat_ws(collect_list)`** then **`sum(price)`**.

**`(or)`**

**`groupBy`** on `lit(1)` and use **`concat_ws(collect_list)`** then **`sum(price)`**.

**`Example:`**

```
df.
agg(concat_ws("-",collect_list(col("name"))).alias("name"),sum("price").alias("price")).
drop("1").
show()

//or using groupBy

df.groupBy(lit(1)).
agg(concat_ws("-",collect_list(col("name"))).alias("name"),sum("price").alias("price")).
drop("1").
show()
//+-----------+-----+
//|       name|price|
//+-----------+-----+
//|abc-pqr-uvw|   42|
//+-----------+-----+
```

Comment: no need to group by 1, 
df.select(concat_ws("-",collect_list(col("name"))).alias("name"),sum("price").alias("price")).show(), 
should work